# Weird behavior of activity life cycle during incoming call : delayed onStop()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have a simple activity without UI. I wanted to check the lifecycle methods of an activity during call.

When a notification for call arrives, nothing happens as expected. When I accept the call, then the activity for call is covering up on my activity. So, ideally `onStop()` should be called immediately. I have checked the logs and only `onPause()` is being called while accepting the call. But after 2-3 seconds `onStop()` is also being called.

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStart: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume: ");
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Logs**

```
05-17 22:10:25.025 E/MainActivity: onStart: 
05-17 22:10:25.054 E/MainActivity: onResume: 


When call has been accepted:
05-17 22:10:34.405 E/MainActivity: onPause: 

After 2-4 seconds:

05-17 22:10:38.144 E/MainActivity: onStop:
```

As per the [**documentation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onStop()) of `onStop()` :

```
Called when you are no longer visible to the user. You will next receive either onRestart(), onDestroy(), or nothing, depending on later user activity.
```

Here, the other activity is covering my activity and hiding it. So, `onStop()` should be called instantly after `onPause()`.

I have tested it on Moto G4 device and Nexus 5 emulator. Both are showing same behavior. 
What is the reason of **delayed onStop()** call?

**Can anyone explain the internal details?**

**Screenshots**
[image: call is running]

Comment: what is launcher mode of your activities?

Comment: @jiteshmohite I have updated the question.

Comment: what about opening other app? does it show similar behavior?

Comment: @Deepakkaku No it calls onStop immediately after onPause

Comment: @KrupalShah have you used any kind of library for calling or call receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onpause):

> After receiving `onPause()` call you will usually receive a following call to
>   onStop() (**after the next activity has been resumed and displayed**),
>   however in **some cases there will be a direct call back to onResume()
>   without going through the stopped state.**

Although the documentation for `onStop()` is a bit perplexing, which claims to call it as soon as Activity is no more visible but there is a slight delay before it gets called (it depends on next activity being displayed).

In case where you receive a call, there is a trivial delay caused after call enters foreground. I have observed this delay on my personal phone too. This delay will cause the `onStop()` call to be delayed.

Comment: I just wanted to know the internal details of that 'trivial delay'. Without a source, we should not simply assume the delay.

Comment: @KrupalShah this delay is caused by the Phone app. It might be trying to load the microphone and/or the output sound (connecting to bluetooh headphone if connected) which could take some time. Since its internal to the phone app, we cannot exactly pin point what causes the delay.

Answer (score 0):

> When I accept the call, then the activity for the call is covering up on my activity. So, ideally onStop() should be called immediately.

Receiving a call does not remove the activity from the task's stack, and will be available when you re-enter the app => onPause() => onStop().

So that's why onStop is not immediately called after the call has been received.

Quoting from [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle)

> If an activity has lost focus but is still visible (that is, a new
>   non-full-sized or transparent activity has focus on top of your
>   activity), it is paused. A paused activity is completely alive (it
>   maintains all state and member information and remains attached to the
>   window manager), but can be killed by the system in extreme low memory
>   situations

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening activity B on top of activity A, this is how the lifecycle would be

1. onPause of activity A is called
2. onCreate of activity B is called
3. onStart of activity B is called
4. onResume of activity B is called
   onStop of activity A is called(with exception of partially visible activity)
5. In case of low memory onDestroy of activity A can also be called

As you can see there are a lot methods called in between onpause and onstop of the activity A, hence the delay

Comment: If you find anything wrong in the answer please care to comment so it can be fixed

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is predictable and documented in [Starting one activity from another](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#soafa)

> Coordinating activities :
>
> Here's the order of operations that occur
>   when Activity A starts Activity B:
>
> 1. Activity A's `onPause()` method executes.
> 2. Activity B's `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, and `onResume()` methods execute in sequence. (Activity B now has user focus.)
> 3. Then, if Activity A is no longer visible on screen, its `onStop()` method executes.

Basically the appearing activity is created and fully initialized between the `onPause()` and `onStop()` callbacks on the disappearing one.
It may take some time, and the `onStop()` method may even not be called at all, for example if the new activity use a dialog style (and thus the old one is still partially visible)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has more to do with the way the call display is implemented. `onPause` is invoked when your activity no longer has primary focus in the foreground, but is still technically "visible". `onStop` is invoked when your activity is no longer visible at all.

It is possible for two activities to have a visible state, which would result in only `onPause` being called for the activity without focus. By displaying the call view on top of your activity, it's possible for your activity to still be "visibile" without being completely gone. Hence why `onPause` is called, but not `onStop`.